# 15A receptacle in kitchen in Canada

Tags: electrical, canada

We have a 15A circuit in the kitchen. Right now there it runs to to a single gang box where it connects to wires that go to the fume hood.  I think the the box was put there to accommodate a switch for the fume hood, but this was never needed, so there is just a cover over the box.  It's white, black and ground in and then white, black and ground out. (The red on the fume hood side isn't connected.) I'd like to put in a 15 Amp duplex receptacle right there.[image]

This is over the counter and it's more than 1.5m from any sink.  (Although it's close to propane stove.)  We are in N.L., which follows the C.E.C.  Besides the fume hood, which is 215W, the circuit currently has about 400W of lights on it.

So can I put a 15A duplex receptacle there with top and bottom outlets connected? If so, should it be GCFI?  If not, can I use a simplex receptacle? (And should that be GFCI?) In short, what are the options?

Comment: I see no reason you couldn't put a GFCI outlet there. To my knowledge there's no rule that you _can't_ have a 15A receptacle in a kitchen--just that you need one or more 20A circuits to meet NEC rules. I'd do it, but let's see what the experts say.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm going to amend the question a bit to cover GCFI.  Since it's more than 1.5m from the sink, I didn't think GCFI would be needed.  There a passel or 20A GCFI receptacles in the kitchen already, but my partner said she's rather have another duplex than a pointless switch and she really doesn't want just a cover.

Comment: You might confuse & confound people by inserting an outlet but _not_ wiring it up just so it "looks normal". Especially if you sell, this may raise red flags with a home inspector if he finds it, and ensure a fine-tooth comb approach to the entire electrical inspection.

Comment: @FreeMan That is a good point.  Using a Decora purely for its decorative value, is not my preferred solution.  I'd rather put in a pointless (but functional) switch; but this idea was vetoed.

Comment: Why would you want to split the receptacle and leave one socket dead as a doornail?  Why not just use a **simplex** (1-socket) receptacle, then?

Comment: Take a blank plate and draw an outlet on it. ;)

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I didn't know there were such things.  That would be a better alternative.  Canadian tire has a GCFI model with a switch and one with a nightlight.  Home hardware has one with 2 USB ports and the nightlight too.

Comment: @Freeman I like it, but I'm not sure it would get the required 2/3 majority vote to make it veto proof.

Comment: Yeah, it helps to shop at places with better selection than Canadian Tire :)  We always preach "real electrical supply" around here, but Home Depot/Lowes should have it.  Normally Amazon is awash with Chinese counterfeits, but simplex receps are probably too "niche" to be counterfeited.   Also, if you need a 1-socket GFCI, they make a GFCI+switch that has 1 socket. I'm quite sure Code prohibits deliberately installing something that is inoperative, so have the switch interrupt hot to the socket :)

Comment: Is that disconnected red wire associated with the cable that brings power to the box or the cable that carries power onward? Does it have power?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It goes to the fume hood.  The other end is also maretted. I don't know why the electrician used 3 conductor wire.  It's a red herring.

Comment: Propane is heavier than air so it would not be an issue.

Comment: Are there enough countertop receptacles already present to meet current CEC standards?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I think there are.